# Android fbconnect

Tags: android

I am trying to implement facebook connect from my android app. When searched for that I got this link http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/. I tried to implement as per their instruction, but i am not getting the output. I first download that, then I import fbconnect-android.zip/api to the eclipse using file-->import. Then I imported android.jar and after i exported that to form an .jar named fbconnect.jar. Then I imported fbconnect-android.zip/sample to the eclipse and imported the fbconnect.jar file as detailed in the site. There is no error in the coding, I have registered in the facebook, i got the key and the secret key. Then also i'm getting the error. In the console i'm getting an error msg like 'Android requires .class compatibility set to 5.0'. I tried to right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties and restart Eclipse after this also the error is still there. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

At least according to this source:

http://excid3.com/blog/2010/06/android-requires-class-compatibility-set-to-5-0/

you now have to build the project again. (Try project > Clean ).

Comment: Thank you Jems for your reply, but I have tried to fix this using the same link that you have gave me. But i'm still getting the error. I have already mention in the message that i have tried to fix the project then I clean that but after that also i'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

i do have the same problem, but i solved it successfully. i think the problem is that you are importing jar files properly into your android project.